# Fonts almost unreadable on Chrome & Firefox (windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, display, browser, fonts

Some websites display text in a weird way (borderline unreadable). 
For example:

1. Facebook or Ebay don't display text correctly
2. Google, Gmail, other websites are ok.

Screenshot illustrating my issue:

[image]

Comment: I don't use Chrome, but if you open Firefox options (click on the "burger" icon top right of your screen, then go to Options), there's a section dealing with fonts. Click on Advanced, then uncheck the "Let websites use their own fonts" box, and restart Firefox. It could or could not solve your problem with Firefox, but it's easy to retrace your steps if it doesn't. Do you have a script blocker enabled, such as NoScript?

Comment: Solved. At least in Firefox. Now, I wonder how it would look if I could see the font's website correctly. Merci bcp. -

Comment: Your images are missing ...

Comment: Avec plaisir... ;-)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks for letting me know, I just fixed it. (hopefully)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

I had 52 Helvetica fonts & the browser was picking a wrong version of this font.

1. Check the font used by the browser on these sites.

   (Open Developer tool: *on Chrome, click on ... > More Tools > developer Tools*)

   In the *style* section, you will see which font is in use.

   In my case it was **HELVETICA NEUE**
2. Check fonts installed on Windows.

   <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > Type **font settings** > Locate **Helvetica**
3. Delete the font. (some of them may be in use, all applications using the font must be closed)
4. Delete font cache:
   `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\FontCache`
5. Helvetica will be replaced by a similar font, usually Arial. Since Helvetica is no longer a standard font on PC.

The issue should be solved.